# Cannot get OpenCV to compile because of undefined references?

Tags: c++, opencv, archlinux

The code is simple and is essentially straight from [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html#load-save-image) tutorial. I am running Arch Linux and have the OpenCV library stored at `/usr/include/`. I have also checked to ensure that `/usr/include` is in my PATH.

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv; 

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    Mat image;
    Mat grayImage; 

    if(!argv[1]){
        std::cerr << "No image data!" << std::endl;
        return -1; 
    }

    image = imread(argv[1], 1);
    cvtColor(image, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    imwrite("Gray_Image.jpg", grayImage);

    namedWindow(argv[1], CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Gray Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    imshow(argv[1], image);
    imshow("Gray Image", grayImage);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler process successfully finds and include these header files, but I still get undefined reference errors at compile-time. If you look into the header files I included they further include other files in `/usr/include/opencv2`. I have checked and such header files do exist.

Any ideas?

```
/tmp/ccudBcqD.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x11f): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x180): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x291): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x2bf): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x2ff): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x32d): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x361): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x383): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/tmp/ccudBcqD.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/ccudBcqD.o: In function `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_[_ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_]+0x111): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
/tmp/ccudBcqD.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x47): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 1.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ "/home/branden/Desktop/OpenCV/test.cpp" -o "/home/branden/Desktop/OpenCV/test"]
[dir: /home/branden/Desktop/OpenCV]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl]
```

Comment: So apparently the solution it to add `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` to the compilation line? What exactly is this doing?

Comment: What's your compiler arguments?

Comment: I was using an IDE, but the default was `g++ file.cpp -o file` where the correct way is apparently `g++ pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv file.cpp -o file`.

Comment: That's because the default is not including the OpenCV libraries. These are link errors, nothing to do with header files.

Comment: -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui

Comment: @sherrellbc it adds the link time library flags like `-lopencv_dnn345 -lopencv_ml345 ...`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is a linker issue. Try:

```
g++ -o test_1 test_1.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

This should work to compile the source. However, if you recently compiled OpenCV from source, you will meet linking issue in run-time, the library will not be found. 
In most cases, after compiling libraries from source, you need to do finally:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: The pkg-config bit should be in backticks. However, they're used by StackOverflow for inline code, so aren't showing up. An alternative syntax is `g++ -o test1 test_1.cpp $(pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs)`.

Comment: This worked for me. Is there a way to link prior to compiling (g++) so these g++ arguments are not required? `sudo ldconfig` doesn't seem to do anything in my case.

Comment: If your'e working with Geany, you might want to set your build command to ``g++ -o "%e" "%f" `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` ``

Comment: It should be in backticks. I was using  this ' near enter,    instead of `  near esc key

Comment: Suppose you are opencv4, you need to use `opencv4` explicitly instead of `opencv`:  `g++ -o test_1 test_1.cpp $(pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs)`

Answer (score 16):

I have tried all solutions. The `-lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui` in comments solved my problem. And now my command line looks like this in geany:

```
g++ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui  -o "%e" "%f"
```

When I build:

```
g++ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui  -o "opencv" "opencv.cpp" (in directory: /home/fedora/Desktop/Implementations)
```

The headers are:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

Comment: In my case they are included with the `pkg-config --cflags --libs ../cmake_bin_dir/instDir/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc` command but it is not working anyway

Answer (score 6):

follow this [tutorial](http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/). i ran the [install-opencv.sh](https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh) file in bash. its in the tutorial

read the example from openCV

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(openCVTest)
# cmake needs this line
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Define project name
project(opencv_example_project)

# Find OpenCV, you may need to set OpenCV_DIR variable
# to the absolute path to the directory containing OpenCVConfig.cmake file
# via the command line or GUI
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

# If the package has been found, several variables will
# be set, you can find the full list with descriptions
# in the OpenCVConfig.cmake file.
# Print some message showing some of them
message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "2.8.11")
    # Add OpenCV headers location to your include paths
    include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

# Declare the executable target built from your sources
add_executable(main main.cpp)

# Link your application with OpenCV libraries
target_link_libraries(main ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

main.cpp

```
/**
 * @file LinearBlend.cpp
 * @brief Simple linear blender ( dst = alpha*src1 + beta*src2 )
 * @author OpenCV team
 */

#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

/** Global Variables */
const int alpha_slider_max = 100;
int alpha_slider;
double alpha;
double beta;

/** Matrices to store images */
Mat src1;
Mat src2;
Mat dst;

//![on_trackbar]
/**
 * @function on_trackbar
 * @brief Callback for trackbar
 */
static void on_trackbar( int, void* )
{
    alpha = (double) alpha_slider/alpha_slider_max ;

    beta = ( 1.0 - alpha );

    addWeighted( src1, alpha, src2, beta, 0.0, dst);

    imshow( "Linear Blend", dst );
}
//![on_trackbar]

/**
 * @function main
 * @brief Main function
 */
int main( void )
{
    //![load]
    /// Read images ( both have to be of the same size and type )
    src1 = imread("../data/LinuxLogo.jpg");
    src2 = imread("../data/WindowsLogo.jpg");
    //![load]

    if( src1.empty() ) { printf("Error loading src1 \n"); return -1; }
    if( src2.empty() ) { printf("Error loading src2 \n"); return -1; }

    /// Initialize values
    alpha_slider = 0;

    //![window]
    namedWindow("Linear Blend", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create Window
    //![window]

    //![create_trackbar]
    char TrackbarName[50];
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "Alpha x %d", alpha_slider_max );
    createTrackbar( TrackbarName, "Linear Blend", &alpha_slider, alpha_slider_max, on_trackbar );
    //![create_trackbar]

    /// Show some stuff
    on_trackbar( alpha_slider, 0 );

    /// Wait until user press some key
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Tested in linux mint 17

Answer (score 4):

if anyone still having this problem. One solution is to rebuild the source OpenCV library using MinGW and not use the binaries given by OpenCV. I did it and it worked like a charm.

Comment: This is actually a perfectly valid answer, as I had to do this on Ubuntu 16.04, with [this version of OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6677#issuecomment-226125483). I could not build [a simple example](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/tree/a46ae0ad7f88b8850a74209a5be8c5d5352726e4/cpp_quick/opencv) on my system without the rebuild - otherwise i would get similar linker errors with the Ubuntu-provided deb. To whomever downvoted this, please reconsider.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible to do this on Ubuntu, right?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error after compiling the opencv4 in linux.

I had to link the libraries after my `.cpp` files not before.

```
g++ $(pkg-config opencv4 --cflags) -std=c++17 foo.cpp $(pkg-config opencv4 --libs) -o foo.o
```

Note: I also passed `-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON` to the `cmake` command to generate the `pkgconfig/opencv4.pc` file - the pkg-config command needs it.

Read here for more info about why the order matters: [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following, you will be able to use opencv build from OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

SET(OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH /home/user/opencv/opencv-2.4.13/release/)

SET(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH}/include/opencv;${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH}/include")

SET(OpenCV_LIB_DIR "${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH}/lib")

LINK_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCV_LIB_DIR})

set(OpenCV_LIBS opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_calib3d opencv_video opencv_features2d opencv_ml opencv_highgui opencv_objdetect opencv_contrib opencv_legacy opencv_gpu)

# find_package( OpenCV )

project(edge.cpp)

add_executable(edge edge.cpp)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this type of error:

```
mingw-w64-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: mingw-w64-x86_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libTransform360.a(VideoFrameTransform.cpp.obj):VideoFrameTransform.cpp:(.text+0xc7c):
undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Rect_<int> const&)'
```

meant load order, I had to do `-lTransform360 -lopencv_dnn345 -lopencv...` just like that, that order.
And putting them right next to each other helped too, don't put `-lTransform360` all the way at the beginning...or you'll get, for some freaky reason:

```
undefined reference to `VideoFrameTransform_new'
undefined reference to `VideoFrameTransform_generateMapForPlane'
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the position of paramters:
g++ -o test2.out test2.cpp `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs`

Before I changed the position I used g++ `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs` test2.cpp -o test2.out.

You can try to run pkg-config opencv  --cflags --libs in terminal or run pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs to see if you can obtain any information.