# opencv tesseract undefined reference error

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract, opencv3.0

I am trying to test tesseract from opencv 3.0 using the test code from [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/end_to_end_recognition.cpp)

However, when I try to compile it, I get the following error

```
     undefined reference to `cv::text::loadClassifierNM1(std::string const&)'
```

Any idea how I can fix this? Your help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

The complete error is

```
    CMakeFiles/text_recog.dir/text_recog.o: In function `main':
    text_recog.cpp:(.text+0x37b): undefined reference to `cv::text::loadClassifierNM1(std::string const&)'
    text_recog.cpp:(.text+0x3bb): undefined reference to `cv::text::createERFilterNM1(cv::Ptr<cv::text::ERFilter::Callback> const&, int, float, float, float, bool, float)'
    text_recog.cpp:(.text+0x42b): undefined reference to `cv::text::loadClassifierNM2(std::string const&)'
    text_recog.cpp:(.text+0x44c): undefined reference to `cv::text::createERFilterNM2(cv::Ptr<cv::text::ERFilter::Callback> const&, float)'
    text_recog.cpp:(.text+0x9c1): undefined reference to `cv::text::erGrouping(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<std::vector<cv::text::ERStat, std::allocator<cv::text::ERStat> >, std::allocator<std::vector<cv::text::ERStat, std::allocator<cv::text::ERStat> > > >&, std::vector<std::vector<cv::Vec<int, 2>, std::allocator<cv::Vec<int, 2> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Vec<int, 2>, std::allocator<cv::Vec<int, 2> > > > >&, std::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > >&, int, std::string const&, float)'
    text_recog.cpp:(.text+0xa95): undefined reference to `cv::text::OCRTesseract::create(char const*, char const*, char const*, int, int)'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [text_recog] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/text_recog.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does this help ?

Comment: Post the full error trace.

Answer (score 1):

It is a linker error. Look at an existing answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26528024/2648754)

You need to compile it as `g++ -o output input.cpp pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` if you are on Linux.

However if you have compiled OpenCV from source on Linux, use `ldconfig` to avoid linking issues.

Comment: This error is slightly different, cuz it is the linking issues with opencv_contrib. Please correct me if am wrong. I included the extra modules and then I recompiled. However, the header files of the extra modules did not add on to the "/usr/include" or "/usr/local/include", which I added manually. Please check the opencv_contrib of opencv3.0 for compiling instructions.

Comment: After compiling the libraries from source, use `sudo ldconfig` and then issue the `g++` command to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You should use library -lopencv_text

```
LIBS += -lopencv_text
```

OR

```
g++ -o output input.cpp -lopencv_text
```