# undefined symbol: _ZTVN2cv11_InputArrayE

Tags: c++, node.js, cmake, opencv3.0

When I was using cmake-js to compile some c++ code which used Opencv, 
the system always output the error:"Error: /home/algorithm/../build/Release/facefind.node: undefined symbol: _ZTVN2cv11_InputArrayE"

can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you manage to compile and link an openCV sample ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337932/cannot-get-opencv-to-compile-because-of-undefined-references if it can help.

Comment: Quick tip: use 'c++filt' to demangle C++ symbols. According to https://d.fuqu.jp/c++filtjs/ this is cv::_InputArray.